# Como puedo crear en una celda los valores de un campo duplicado y dejarlo unico en python?

Tags: python

acudo a su apoyo en indicarme como podria realizar lo siguiente en python:

Tengo el siguiente Dataframe con IDs duplicados y estoy tratando de que quede solo un ID unico pero en la columna Value quede con los valores de los duplicados eliminados

Original:

[image: Original]

Esperado:

[image: Esperado]

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: a la hora de hacer el group le das alguna especificacion ya que al no saber que conservar y que no los conserva todos?  podrias colocar el codigo de lo que as intentando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma de agrupar por el id es usar `groupby("id")`, pero la forma de agregarlo después para que aparezcan los valores en la columna value depende de qué pretendes hacer exactamente y de qué tipos sean los valores originales en esa columna.

Si se trata de cadenas como en tu ejemplo, podrías hacer por ejemplo:

```py
df.groupby("id").agg(lambda x: ",".join(x))
```

La función `.agg()` agrega los datos de un grupo, usando para ello la función que tú le pases como parámetro, que en este caso es una lambda que simplemente concatena todos los valores separándolos con una coma.

### Demo

```py
import pandas as pd

# Creamos un dataframe de ejemplo
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3],
                   "value": list("ABCDABCDABCDE")})
print(df)
```

```
    id value
0    1     A
1    1     B
2    1     C
3    1     D
4    2     A
5    2     B
6    2     C
7    2     D
8    3     A
9    3     B
10   3     C
11   3     D
12   3     E
```

Y agrupamos como mostré antes:

```py
result = df.groupby("id").agg(lambda x: ",".join(x))
print(result)
```

```
        value
id           
1     A,B,C,D
2     A,B,C,D
3   A,B,C,D,E
```

### Variantes

Si los datos de la columna no son cadenas, el join no funcionará, pero puedes convertirlos en cadenas:

```
df.groupby("id").agg(lambda x: ",".join(str(e) for e in x))
```

Otra forma más general que vale para cualquier tipo de dato es hacer que la lambda retorne una lista con los elementos:

```
df.groupby("id").agg(lambda x: list(x))
```

En este caso los contenidos de la columna "values" serían listas:

```
              value
id                 
1      [A, B, C, D]
2      [A, B, C, D]
3   [A, B, C, D, E]
```

lo que puede ser incluso más conveniente, pues te hace posible iterar por ellos si quisieras:

```
# Procesar los valores correspondientes al id 3
for elem in result.loc[3].value:
  print(elem)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, me sacaste de un aprieto, saludos